# Azure Automation Runbook input IP Addresses as String array parameter

Tags: json, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to input a list of IP addresses as a string array in Azure Automation. I get "invalid JSON primitive: 10.10.3.0" when I used JSON format

```
['10.10.3.0/24', '10.10.4.0/24']
```

Am I supposed to escape the forward slash?

```
[string] $backendAddressPoolName  = "backendPool",
[string[]] $backendIPAddresses,
```

That's it. These are the parameters to my runbook. Azure Automation won't accept

```
["10.10.3.0/24", "10.10.4.0/24"]
```

As an input for backendIPAddresses

Comment: valie json will look like this: `["10.10.3.0/24","10.10.4.0/24"]`, https://jsonlint.com/. escaping is not necessary, afaik

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: well, i'd really like to help you, but you do not show your code, so all I can tell is - this json is valid. i dont know wth are you doing in the code

Comment: I edited it to show the parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
param(
    [string[]]$backendIPAddresses
)

$backendipaddresses | % { "input: $_" }
```

Input this exactly: ["str1","str2"] - this has to be valid json

[image]

json validator: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Does that include if I wanted to input a " / " ?
The issues from wanting to use the IP addresses I had

Comment: yeah. also '10.0.0.0/24' isnt an ip address. its a subnet range.

Comment: ["10.10.3.0", "10.10.4.0"]

even just listing the IP address... I get "invalid JSON primitive: 10.10.3.0"

Comment: $backendipaddresses | % { "input: $_" }

if I include this.. what is input? does it just convert it?

Comment: its just to showcase that it processes them one by one. can you post the screenshot (into the question) of your code and how you test it?

Comment: Ah.. when looking at the screenshots for some reason I decided to convert that input from JSON when I didn't need to... Thanks for taking the time to help.